# array.push add integer as string

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

hi im using laravel with vuejs and javascript code and this is my vuejs code

```
for(i = 0;i<response['data'].length;i++)
{
    this.edited_lines.push(
        {
            id:response['data'][i]['id'], // this is integer
            cost_center_id:response['data'][i]['cost_center_id'], // this is integer
            credit:response['data'][i]['note'], // this is string
        }
    );
}
```

till now everything is so good .. 
but in my blade i did this code

```
<tr v-for='line , id in edited_lines'>
    <td>
        @php   $cost_center_id = "{{line['cost_center_id']}}"; @endphp
         {{gettype($cost_center_id)}}  // this always resturn string not integer 
    </td>
</tr>
```

and becuase its always return string not integer 
if i did this in my blade i gat error

```
{{$cost_center_id * 1}} // if i put this code in my blade i gat error below
A non-numeric value encountered
```

i tried to do this ..

```
cost_center_id:1,
```

and get the same error 
any help here thanks ..

Comment: Convert to number: https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: i did this $cost_center_id = "{{Number(line['cost_center_id'])}}";  but same result